# Displaying app permissions in a web dash board

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

My mobile app (both iOS and Android) will not "work" without the user giving my app some permissions (example: if locations is set to "Never" then the app is worthless as geo-tracking is a core functionality. The app explains this to the user and asks them to please change the setting (there are lots of good design patterns out there for that).

So far so good.

The app has a web backend. It would be helpful for troubleshooting to know what permissions that user has given the app. This way we can see which users haven't given us the permissions we need.

I am curious how this should be handled from a privacy policy standpoint? I do want to tell users that we can see this information and it is only to assist us in troubleshooting. I don't want to just include a toggle to opt in or out if I can help it, as it kind of defeats the purpose of knowing what the settings are.

The reason I would like to know what their permissions are is that by the nature of the app the user needs to set the permissions "correctly" **before** they start on some trips.

Possibly we should just not let the user actually use the app if the settings are not what we need?

Are there norms around this? Is it a terrible idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on a couple of business-critical apps where permissions (eg. location) are needed for core functions and the bottom line. In this case and I'm sure other situations, it's perfectly acceptable in my opinion to prevent app usage when permissions aren't granted. I don't think it's a norm per say, probably because many or even most apps include some function that still works, ie. the app isn't rendered worthless lacking one or two permissions.

However, the answer here might depend in part on just what kind of app it is, and if you can afford to frustrate some users or get a few bad ratings in the app store. Probably preferable to just completely preventing usage would be to take the user to a "help" screen where you inform them about permissions, etc. and possibly even provide a link, email, or phone for support contact if they have questions and concerns.

As far as privacy policy goes, I don't see it as an issue. The user should already realize when prompted for the permission that the app (and potentially its backend) knows their response. Having said that, it certainly doesn't hurt to inform them that they're being watched. Well, that is, if you explain it in some nicer way than "you're being watched". :) Do you check and re-prompt for permission the next time they reach that part of the app or the next time they launch the app? This gives them a chance to change their response and helps make them aware of the permission's importance, but your user-friendly in-app explanations will help too.

You could have a custom web dashboard for this, but why not just use Google Analytics, Fabric, Firebase or something similar to collect this information? Though, maybe you need a dashboard because it's friendlier for customer service reps or other non-developers? That would make sense to me.